# Override type on Types.ps1xml for a PowerShell binary module

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a binary module, and I'm including a Cmdlet that uses a custom type.
The type is a C# class that inherits from `System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity`.

PowerShell has a built in module, called `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security`. This module have a `Types.ps1xml` file, which contains a definition for `System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity` objects.

My problem is that this `Types` file is breaking some of my object's properties.
I tried defining my type in my module's `Types.ps1xml` file, but the problem persists.

You can find the definition for my type here: [WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceSecurity](https://github.com/FranciscoNabas/WindowsUtils/blob/remservice-dotnetvers/Engine/AccessControl.cs)

My `WindowsUtils.Types.ps1xml`

```xml
<Type>
  <Name>WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceSecurity</Name>
  <Members>
    <MemberSet>
      <Name>PSStandardMembers</Name>
      <Members>
        <PropertySet>
          <Name>DefaultDisplayPropertySet</Name>
          <ReferencedProperties>
            <Name>Name</Name>
            <Name>Owner</Name>
            <Name>Access</Name>
          </ReferencedProperties>
        </PropertySet>
      </Members>
    </MemberSet>
  </Members>
</Type>
```

Their `Security.Types.ps1xml`

```xml
<Type>
  <Name>System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity</Name>
  <Members>
    <CodeProperty>
      <Name>Path</Name>
      <GetCodeReference>
        <TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase</TypeName>
        <MethodName>GetPath</MethodName>
      </GetCodeReference>
    </CodeProperty>
    <CodeProperty>
      <Name>Owner</Name>
      <GetCodeReference>
        <TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase</TypeName>
        <MethodName>GetOwner</MethodName>
      </GetCodeReference>
    </CodeProperty>
    <CodeProperty>
      <Name>Group</Name>
      <GetCodeReference>
        <TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase</TypeName>
        <MethodName>GetGroup</MethodName>
      </GetCodeReference>
    </CodeProperty>
    <CodeProperty>
      <Name>Access</Name>
      <GetCodeReference>
        <TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase</TypeName>
        <MethodName>GetAccess</MethodName>
      </GetCodeReference>
    </CodeProperty>
    <CodeProperty>
      <Name>Sddl</Name>
      <GetCodeReference>
        <TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase</TypeName>
        <MethodName>GetSddl</MethodName>
      </GetCodeReference>
    </CodeProperty>
    <ScriptProperty>
      <Name>AccessToString</Name>
      <GetScriptBlock>
        $toString = "";
        $first = $true;
        if ( ! $this.Access ) { return "" }
        foreach($ace in $this.Access)
        {
        if($first)
        {
        $first = $false;
        }
        else
        {
        $tostring += "`n";
        }
        $toString += $ace.IdentityReference.ToString();
        $toString += " ";
        $toString += $ace.AccessControlType.ToString();
        $toString += "  ";
        if($ace -is [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule])
        {
        $toString += $ace.FileSystemRights.ToString();
        }
        elseif($ace -is  [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule])
        {
        $toString += $ace.RegistryRights.ToString();
        }
        }
        return $toString;
      </GetScriptBlock>
    </ScriptProperty>
    <ScriptProperty>
      <Name>AuditToString</Name>
      <GetScriptBlock>
        $toString = "";
        $first = $true;
        if ( ! (&amp; { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.audit }) ) { return "" }
        foreach($ace in (&amp; { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.audit }))
        {
        if($first)
        {
        $first = $false;
        }
        else
        {
        $tostring += "`n";
        }
        $toString += $ace.IdentityReference.ToString();
        $toString += " ";
        $toString += $ace.AuditFlags.ToString();
        $toString += "  ";
        if($ace -is [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule])
        {
        $toString += $ace.FileSystemRights.ToString();
        }
        elseif($ace -is [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule])
        {
        $toString += $ace.RegistryRights.ToString();
        }
        }
        return $toString;
      </GetScriptBlock>
    </ScriptProperty>
  </Members>
</Type>
```

This is when I call my Cmdlet and it returns all properties correctly:

```
C:\>_ Get-ServiceSecurity WindowsUtils_Pester_Service | fl *

Name                    : WindowsUtils_Pester_Service
Owner                   : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Group                   : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
AccessToString          : NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE Allow UserDefinedControl, GenericRead
                          NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE Allow UserDefinedControl, GenericRead
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow QueryConfig, QueryStatus, EnumerateDependents, Interrogate, GenericExecute
                          BUILTIN\Administrators Allow AllAccess
AuditToString           :
Sddl                    : O:SYG:SYD:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
Access                  : {WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAccessRule, WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAccessRule, WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAccessRule,
                          WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAccessRule}
Audit                   : {}
AccessRightType         : WindowsUtils.Engine.ServiceRights
AccessRuleType          : WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAccessRule
AuditRuleType           : WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAuditRule
AreAccessRulesProtected : False
AreAuditRulesProtected  : False
AreAccessRulesCanonical : True
AreAuditRulesCanonical  : True
_rawSecDescriptor       : System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor
_securityDescriptor     : System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor
```

Here you can see the property `Path`, which my object does not use.

```
C:\>_ Get-ServiceSecurity WindowsUtils_Pester_Service

Path Owner               Access
---- -----               ------
     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE Allow UserDefinedControl, GenericRead…
```

When I just load the module, all the properties are fine, but after using it extensively the properties are swapped out.
Here is `Get-Member` with the normal properties:

```
Access                          Property   WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAccessRule[] Access {get;}
AccessRightType                 Property   type AccessRightType {get;}
AccessRuleType                  Property   type AccessRuleType {get;}
AccessToString                  Property   string AccessToString {get;}
AreAccessRulesCanonical         Property   bool AreAccessRulesCanonical {get;}
AreAccessRulesProtected         Property   bool AreAccessRulesProtected {get;}
AreAuditRulesCanonical          Property   bool AreAuditRulesCanonical {get;}
AreAuditRulesProtected          Property   bool AreAuditRulesProtected {get;}
Audit                           Property   WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAuditRule[] Audit {get;}
AuditRuleType                   Property   type AuditRuleType {get;}
AuditToString                   Property   string AuditToString {get;}
Group                           Property   string Group {get;}
Name                            Property   string Name {get;}
Owner                           Property   string Owner {get;}
Sddl                            Property   string Sddl {get;}
_rawSecDescriptor               Property   System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor _rawSecDescriptor {get;}
_securityDescriptor             Property   System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor _securityDescriptor {get;}
```

And here when it breaks:

```
AccessRightType                 Property       type AccessRightType {get;}
AccessRuleType                  Property       type AccessRuleType {get;}
AreAccessRulesCanonical         Property       bool AreAccessRulesCanonical {get;}
AreAccessRulesProtected         Property       bool AreAccessRulesProtected {get;}
AreAuditRulesCanonical          Property       bool AreAuditRulesCanonical {get;}
AreAuditRulesProtected          Property       bool AreAuditRulesProtected {get;}
Audit                           Property       WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceAuditRule[] Audit {get;}
AuditRuleType                   Property       type AuditRuleType {get;}
Name                            Property       string Name {get;}
_rawSecDescriptor               Property       System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor _rawSecDescriptor {get;}
_securityDescriptor             Property       System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor _securityDescriptor {get;}
AccessToString                  ScriptProperty System.Object AccessToString {get=$toString = "";…
AuditToString                   ScriptProperty System.Object AuditToString {get=$toString = "";…
```

I don't want to change the property names, because they are the same thing, but implemented differently. The whole point of this custom type is making the Cmdlet familiar with the existing ones.
Anyone have any idea on how to overcome this?

Comment: Can you edit your question, removing the pictures of your code, replacing the pictures with the text of your code, formatted as `code` using the `{}` button

Comment: To find the properties use something like AccessToString | Format-List

Comment: Rather than giving a extensive description of what you trying to do, try to build a [mcve] which usually holds more details e.g. "*my type*" a C# class or PowerShell Class? Anyways, I don't think there is any serializer (including the [PSSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psserializer) which is apparently involved here) that can hold custom properties/objects. Maybe a simple (re)constructor in your own type that rebuilds the properties is the solution...

Comment: Changed the question to be more clear, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

So at the end I couldn't find a way to overcome this. So I created a base class with the key features from `System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity`.
Then Added the `WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceSecurity` to my `Types.ps1xml`, and created a `Format.ps1xml` to mimic the `Access <-> AccessToString` table format.
Won't put the full code here because it's extensive, but you can find it here: [WindowsUtils.AccessControl.WindowsUtilsObjectSecurity](https://github.com/FranciscoNabas/WindowsUtils/blob/remservice-dotnetvers/Engine/AccessControl.cs).

Eventually this link will be unavailable, so you can get it on the main. [WindowsUtils.AccessControl.WindowsUtilsObjectSecurity](https://github.com/FranciscoNabas/WindowsUtils/blob/main/Engine/AccessControl.cs)

The `Types.ps1xml` entry.

```
<Type>
  <Name>WindowsUtils.AccessControl.ServiceSecurity</Name>
  <Members>
    <MemberSet>
      <Name>PSStandardMembers</Name>
      <Members>
        <PropertySet>
          <Name>DefaultDisplayPropertySet</Name>
          <ReferencedProperties>
            <Name>Name</Name>
            <Name>Owner</Name>
            <Name>Access</Name>
          </ReferencedProperties>
        </PropertySet>
        <PropertySet>
          <Name>DefaultKeyPropertySet</Name>
          <ReferencedProperties>
            <Name>Name</Name>
          </ReferencedProperties>
        </PropertySet>
      </Members>
    </MemberSet>
  </Members>
</Type>
```

The `Format.ps1xml` entry. (Got from DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml).

```
<View>
    <Name>System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>

    <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
            <TableColumnHeader>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Access</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
         </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
            <TableRowEntry>
                <TableColumnItems>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Path</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Owner</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>AccessToString</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                </TableColumnItems>
            </TableRowEntry>
         </TableRowEntries>
    </TableControl>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I create a "derived" class for PowerShell when using C# without having to define an actual derived class in C# or when a class is marked as sealed.

Create a new `PSObject` from the object you want to "derive". Then invoke the `Insert` method on the `TypeNames` property of the new `PSObject`, using an index of 0 and the name of the type that you want to use. Finally write the new `PSObject` to the output pipe.

```
PSObject pso = new PSObject(MyObject);
pso.TypeNames.Insert(0, "Namespace1.Namespace2.TypeName");
WriteObject(pso);
```

Now when you pipe the output from your command to `Get-Member`, it will show `Namespace1.Namespace2.TypeName` as the object's typename. You can also examine object's hidden property `PSTypeNames`. This will show all of the derived typenames for the object with yours listed first. Don't forget to change the typename in your custom Types.ps1xml/Formats.ps1xml files to reflect the new "derived" type.

Comment: The whole point is to have a derived class, so I can use the APIs, and the Cmdlet looks familiar with existing ones. It's at the end of the question.